# jQuery bind firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

```
$(".container").on("contextmenu", ".photos-bottom .albums li", function(e) {

$('html').bind('click', function (event) {
    alert(id);
});

return false;
});
```

when I right click (for the contextmenu) multiple times and then left click html once, it triggers the alert the number of times that I right clicked.

So if I right click once, then left click, it shows a popup once.
If I right click three times, then left click, it shows the popup three times.

Why is this so?

Comment: what are you trying to do with that code? attaching `click` event to `html`?

Comment: Why do you re-bind the `click` handler in the `contextmenu` handler? This does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: This is a popup, and when I bind click to html it's so when i click outside of the popup it fires this event to close the menu, and whatever else. (There's a lot more code to this, so there's a lot you don't see)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`$('html').unbind('click').bind('click')` fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, but in order for it to work as it needs to it needs to bind only when the menu has been opened.

Answer (score 4):

Because your click event is being bound every time a context menu event occurs, you're actually adding an additional bind each time you right click. This is the reason for the ever-growing number of event executions.

You should either:

a) unbind the event when the context menu is closed, or

b) bind the click event outside of your contextmenu callback function.

Comment: Thanks, yeah upon more work doing this fixes it:

$('html').unbind('click').bind('click')

Comment: glad I could be of service :)