# Click event shows alert multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to bind a click event to an element using jQuery. I noticed that any `alert` or `window.open` or `window.showModalDialog` inside the callback function is showed 3 times in Safari and Chrome (OS X 10.8.3 / Safari 6.0.1 / Chrome 26 beta). firefox works fine.

But when I do `console.log` it's fine and it just logs only one time (as expected).

I also tried binding the event using .click and .bind and older versions of jQuery, but all of them are the same.

I also triggered the click event with .trigger('click') and it worked fine as expected. So I guessed that my OS or browsers are faulty, but then the console.log thing should have logged 3 times too not one.

Here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/t6DBa/3/

Thanks.

Comment: Clicking the image in Chrome shows the alert once for me.

Comment: only shows once for me. using chrome.

Comment: i can only see it once

Comment: @all : It shows only once :)

Comment: For me works perfect. Using chrome.

Comment: When I log `e` it logs this three times: http://d.pr/i/TTiD

Comment: I guess you just have a magical mouse....

Comment: These might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909526/jquery-callbacks-being-called-multiple-times
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047656/jquery-bind-firing-multiple-times

Comment: @MobinRanjbar tried all. didn't help.

Comment: @ArashMilani OS X 10.8.3 / Safari 6.0.1 / Chrome 26 beta

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my case when I am logging, I am getting one time alert message in firefox (46.0b9) and chrome(Version 49.0.2623.112 m) but in safari(5.1.7) I am getting it five times.