# iframe loads multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a problem with iframes. The problem is that I have a main page and menu which loads a content with iframe. On main page I have also a div "MessageBox" In one iframe I display content of variable in "MessageBox", so I have a full screen message on my MAIN page.

example in iframe I have button which generate this:

```
        content="<input type='button' value='OK' class='Ok' id='Ok'/>";
        MessageBox("Click OK", content, "child", "400", "170");
```

In iFrame I have jquery function:

```
$(".Ok",window.parent.document).live("click",function(){
    alert("OK");
});
```

and everything if OK, only when I enter on this iframe at the first time. I see alert("OK") and its cool, but when I click other iframe from menu and again this iframe I see alert("OK") two times, when I click again other iframe and back to this Iframe I see 3 times alert("OK").

Can someone help me with this issue? Is there any iframe cache or something like that? I think that every time I open my iframe it is stored in memory and that why I have many calsses ".Ok" and when I click button "OK" the libe click method is executed as many times as I have stored iframes in memory?

Please help :)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047656/jquery-bind-firing-multiple-times

Comment: You're assigning the click event handler to the partent window every time you change the iframe source, so you end up with multiple functions running.

Comment: I tried unbind('click') and die() $(".Ok",window.parent.document).die().live("click ... | $(".Ok",window.parent.document).unbind('click').live("click ... but its not helped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that every time you are adding another `iframe` from menu, you are registring new click handler to every element with `'.Ok'` class, so also for every iframe element you already loaded.

Edit: To register the click only for the `.Ok` element in the iframe use:
`$('.Ok').live('click', function() {...});`
without the scope to the parent window.
BTW: `$('...').live(...)` is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: OK, so is there easy way to correct this? maybe just content="<input type='button' value='OK' class='Ok' id='Ok' ONCLICK="func"/>"; ?

Comment: but when I add onClick to the button I will have to add "func" in main page and I wish to have this function in iframe. Is there any solution?

Comment: Nope :( now click function is not executed.

Comment: I use jquery 1.6, there is no on function in it. I also tried this with "delegate" but still worked as I described.

Comment: For that case you can try it with $(".Ok", window.document).live(...)

Comment: See my pastebin: http://pastebin.com/qCk3BQxm There are two iframes in the page, but click handler are added only one time.